# Different ways to create an instant of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the difference between:

```
user = User.new(name: "David", occupation: "Code Artist")
```

and

```
user = User.new do |u|
  u.name = "David"
  u.occupation = "Code Artist"
end
```

Doesn't both of them create a new instant of User?

Comment: Yes, both of them create a new instant of `User`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one very important difference here. When you pass a hash to the constructor, rails passes this hash to `assign_attributes` method, which can do some magic around this hash.

Firstly, in rails 4 it can reject the params hash (which is tainted, will work fine otherwise) if it has not got through strong attributes logic. In rails 3 it will reject the whole hash if at least one of the params is not marked as `attr_accessible`.

In addition, `assign_attributes` can accept complex data structures in a form they come from the form. I.e. it will accept params like `date(3i), date(2i), date(1i)`, will check the model column `date`. If it finds it is in fact a date (database column type), it will create a new Date object from those data and will assign it instead.

None of this functionality is available with block code, unless you call `assign_attributes` there directly.